# Zabbix trigger alert immediately and not accordingly to the sec input value

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have a Zabbix item with a key `celery_worker.docker` that reads from the `zabbix_agentd.conf`

```
userparameter=celery_worker.docker, sudo docker ps -f "status=running" | grep worker
```

I want to know when it is down for the last 15min.
I have trigger with:

```
 {celery_worker.docker.str(ago,300)}=0
```

But it alerts immediately and not after 300 seconds.
(I checked by testing and the alert is right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [trigger function page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions), it explains that `str` will look for one occurrence of the string in the specified period.

You might be able to achieve the desired result with the `count` function (see the same page for detail).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I'm tryimg this {celery_worker.docker.count(5m,ago,like)}=0   but it still fire before 5m left :-(

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit more about the values that item is getting - what does "ago" imply, and what you want to detect.